# Ubuntu 18.04 React Native Run Android javax.net.ssl.SSLException

Tags: android, react-native, ubuntu-18.04

When I am running `react-native run-android` command on Ubuntu 18.04 it is showing -

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran `sudo rm /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` and then I ran `sudo update-ca-certificates -f` . This resolves the issue

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, it was because of the Java version.

So, uninstall Java using this link
https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java

Then install Oracle JDK 8

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```